# Как сделать обновление диалога пользователей без обновления страницы в php

Tags: php

Как так сделать?
Я делаю систему диалогов пользователей.
И мне нужно чтоб когда один человек отправлял сообщение у друго-го оно появлялясь без обновления страницы.
Я использую:
php 7.1.5
Mysql
Phpmyadmin
Выглядит форма так
[image: выглядит это так]

Вот код
https://pastebin.com/CSfS9NZ1
В код добавлены комментарии

Зарание спасибо.

Comment: ajax (9 символов нужно...)

Comment: AJAX или WebSocket используйте

Comment: В данном случае лучше использовать long pool запросы. Отправляешь запрос на сервер, сервер в свою очередь отвечает только при каком либо событии.

Comment: Ну я использую ajax, но уменя пользователь не может прокручивать диалог, страница часто обновляется

Comment: Отряд экстрасенсов получил приглашение в данный диалог. Ждём. П.С, прикрепите ваш код чтобы не ждать прибытия отряда.

Comment: дак не надо целиком закгружать диалог при каждом обновлении, а добавлять только новое в конец

Comment: Сейчас загружу часть кода в вопрос

Comment: Всё я загрузил скриншоты с кодом.

Comment: никому тут не нужны скриншоты с кодом, вставляйте текстом

Comment: Вот код https://pastebin.com/CSfS9NZ1

Comment: [Первая ссылка из гугл](https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=607), для начала поучите основы и т.п. поюзайте примеры и поучитесь

Comment: Блин там не понятно, я новичок в php. Можно как-то по проще

Comment: Проще - это на листе написать и по почте отправить. Чтобы что-то написать, учиться надо. Гуглите, смотрите, разбирайтесь, через какое-то время накопите достаточно знаний для написания чата