# Как сделать чтоб страница с диалогом автоматически обновлялась (php)

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, phpmyadmin

Как так сделать?
Я делаю систему диалогов пользователей.
И мне нужно чтоб когда один человек отправлял сообщение у друго-го оно появляясь без обновления страницы.
Я использую:
php 7.1.5
Mysql
Phpmyadmin
Выглядит форма так
[image: выглядит это так]

Вот [код](https://pastebin.com/CSfS9NZ1). В код добавлены комментарии

Зарание спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать обновление диалога пользователей без обновления страницы в php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947043/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-php)

Comment: тогда вам нужен ajax или websocket ... теги ставьте такие, а лучше почитайте в сети ...с ajax проще хотя уже не в моде так как есть круче технология но для начала и ajax хватит

Comment: Он уже стоит, но баг есть что не пролистывается диалог вниз, это из-за частого обновления диалога

Comment: Так в JS обавьте чтоб скроллил при каждом апдейте вниз

Comment: Я в js не разбираюсь, ну и есть баг что в поле для ввода не водится сообщение по тойже причине

Answer (score 0):

Здесь необходимо использовать AJAX, если в JS не разбираетесь, советую почитать на эту тему литературы, так как все современные сайты строятся в связке JS+CSS+HTML ну и PHP могут докинуть для серверной части. Да и в гугле полно информации насчет создания диалогов в реальном времени

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйся технологиями AJAX, все что связано с работой php на веб-страницах без их дальнейшей перезагрузки - это все AJAX.